# CodeChef shows gets() is not declared under any scope. Works properly on Codeblocks though

Tags: c++

I have used cstdio for using the gets() function but still CodeChef shows the not declared error. Any solutions ?

Comment: Yes I did. Even <stdio.h> worked on CodeBlocks.

Comment: I suggest you add your solution as an answer and mark it as the accepted solution in order to help others who may face the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Gets function is deprecated since c++11 as said in [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/)
Use scanf instead:

```
scanf("%[^\n]",string-array);
```

This will take an input and interrupt when it encounter a newline char

Comment: Isn't scanf a function exclusive to C ?

Comment: @ManishKumar Actually it is supported by the latest c++ implementation, but if you want at this point simply use std::cin stream friendly input method